# What's the Rails 3 replacement for ActiveRecord::Errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What's the Rails 3 replacement for ActiveRecord::Errors?

In Rails 2.3.8, this is an object:

```
>> ActiveRecord::Errors
=> ActiveRecord::Errors
```

In Rails 3.0.0rc, you get a NameError:

```
>> ActiveRecord::Errors
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors
 from (irb):2
```

I'm trying to make the [wizardly](http://github.com/gaveeno/wizardly) generator work with Rails 3.

```
$ rails g wizardly_scaffold home
```

But it fails:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/wizardly_gt-0.1.8.9/lib/validation_group.rb:150:
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors (NameError)
```

The line it refers to is this:

```
ActiveRecord::Errors.send :include, ValidationGroup::ActiveRecord::Errors
```

Earlier in the file, we see:

```
module ValidationGroup
  module ActiveRecord
...
    module Errors # included in ActiveRecord::Errors
      def add_with_validation_group(attribute, msg = I18n.translate('activerecord.errors.messages')[:invalid], *args, &block)
        add_error = @base.respond_to?(:should_validate?) ? (@base.should_validate?(attribute.to_sym) || attribute == :base) : true
        add_without_validation_group(attribute, msg, *args, &block) if add_error
      end
...
end
```

Comment: Ryan points out the correct replacement below. However, this isn't enough to get wizardly working (or even getting the scaffolds working). That'll require significant work.

Comment: Did you eventually get wizardly working with Rails 3?

Comment: I did not. I tried using grouped_validation (which works with rails 3) instead of validationgroup, but never got it up and running. I switched back to rails 2.3.8 to proceed with the project.

If you'd like, I can dig up my hacked version of wizardly for you to continue working on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That'd be `ActiveModel::Errors`. Things such as validations and error handling have been moved over to Active Model to provide a common API for all ORM Railties such as Active Record, Data Mapper, Mongoid etc. to hook into Rails with.

It would appear the wizardly plugin needs to check for ActiveModel first and if it exists, then include the error handling there rather than `ActiveRecord::Errors`. A trivial change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this gem

http://rubygems.org/gems/wizardly_gt

I have only just begin playing with wizardly, but the above at least seems to be compatible with Rails 3.

Comment: I've used wizardly_gt and emailed Gavin. It doesn't work with Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

Wizardly obviously does a lot more, but you should check out [validation_scopes](https://rubygems.org/gems/validation_scopes), which I just updated for Rails3 compatibility.  Rather than grouping things by attributes, it just lets you explicitly declare different groups of validations by creating namespaced collections of errors.  Internally it's a much simpler implementation (the same code handles Rails 2 and 3).  Personally I find this to be more flexible than grouping by attribute (what if an attribute should have different constraints in different steps of a wizard for instance?).